# Adding class onLoad using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm currently making a navigation with `.active` `class` as the user scrolls, but the first anchor doesn't have an `.active` `class` unless you will scroll. Anyway, it's quite hard to explain.
Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7nrLU/5/
Feel free to suggest other better way, but not CSS3. Thank you!

Comment: You could put $('.navigation a.a1').addClass('active'); inside document ready, before $(window).bind(...?

Comment: Can't you just put the class in the markup?

Comment: @AlexBall, thanks you! It works. Musa, I think it's better if jquery will do that =)

Comment: @user1441816, I am happy that it works, I post as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add my solution, in addition to other viable solutions ;-)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.navigation a.a1').addClass('active');
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking forward on you answer lately. =)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.scroll()` to immediatly run the event, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7nrLU/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navigation a:first').addClass('active');
```